# Perform matrix algebra without specifying Matrix elements, but using the matrix objects as elemental

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Is there any functionality in Mathematica that let's the user work directly with matrix objects (potentially of non-defined size), eg. solving a matrix equality for the matrix object without necessarily specifying all elements of the matrix. What I want to do is to manipulate matrix equations while using the matrix objects as elemental, so eg solving a matrix equation for a matrix object (and not for all its elements explicitly.

As a simple example of what I mean: say I'd want to check if two matrix inequalities are equivalent eg. and let's say there is a function `matrix[A]` that declares that A may be of dimension >2.

```
matrix[A]
matrix[B]
matrix[C]
```

In principle that would have to be like an element function, like:

```
element[A, Reals[dim=n]]
```

Then there should be a function MatrixSolve[] such that

```
In: Assuming[A is square and det[A]==0, MatrixSolve[A*B==C,B]]
Out:B->A^(-1)*C.
```

Or for example:

```
Q:=A*B   *so Q must also be a matrix*
In: Assuming[again the necessary stuff like A square..., Q*A^(-1)===B]]
Out: True
```

I have not found any such functionalities in the documentation (or in the search function on SE) and was wondering if there is a way to implement this and, if not, why such features would not exist.

Comment: This might get (better) answers at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com but if you do decide to post it there take it down from here, cross-posting is rather frowned upon.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15335/19530